# How can I get a variable or state from a another VScode extension ?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am writing an extension than need to check the state of another extension ? Is there a way to check for available variables from a vscode extension ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible if the extension you want to check on provides an API as described [in this docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/vscode-api#_extensions), otherwise it is not possible.